# Recurring decimal and GIF

Tags: number-theory, real-numbers, irrational-numbers

What is the difference between $2.\bar{9}$ and $3$? Are they really equal? Then why is $2.\bar{9} = 2$ and $[3]=3$? And in high school, why do we learn $2.\bar{9} =  3$? Is there any satisfying argument about this?

($[ \ ]$ denotes GIF)

Comment: What is GIF in this context ? Surely not the image format ...

Comment: Greatest integer function

Comment: A now more common form is to replace brackets [ ... ]  by $ \lfloor ... \rfloor $ that you write \lfloor 2.99 \rfloor (enclosed by dollar signs)

Comment: No contradiction $\lfloor 2.99...9 \rfloor = 2$ as long as **there is a finite number of $9$s**... Otherwise, if the number of $9$s is infinite it is equal to $3$.

Comment: $\lfloor 2.999\ldots\rfloor$ is not $2$; it is $3$, precisely because $2.999\ldots=3$.

Comment: So why is 2.99....= 3

Comment: $3-2.999\ldots=0.000\ldots=0$

Comment: In addition to the answers below, you can read about why $0.999\ldots=1$ [on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/0.999...) and then add $2$ to both sides.

Comment: @JeanMarie you may enclose code by backticks '\`' to highlight your code `\lfloor 2.99 \rfloor `.

Comment: @GNUSupporter 8964民主女神 地下教會 Thanks. I will know for next time.

Answer (score 5):

Actually this is an interesting question: the discrepancy given by the GIF function you mention, or simply called floor function, on the number $2.9999\dots$ is due to the discountinuity of this function at any integer point.

For any number of the sequence $a_0=2$, $a_1=2.9$, $a_2=2.99$, $a_3=2.999$ and so forth the GIF function is indeed $2$ and hence
$$\lim_{n}\lfloor a_n \rfloor=\lim_{n\to \infty}\lfloor 2.99\dots9 \rfloor=2$$
**but** if you exchange the limit and the function, then the limit  $\lim_{n\to \infty}a_n=2.99\dots\equiv 3$ thus 
$$\lfloor\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n\rfloor=\lfloor 3\rfloor=3.$$

---

Without sequences, this is saying that
$$\lim_{x\nearrow 3^-}\lfloor x\rfloor=2\neq 3=\lim_{x\searrow 3^+}\lfloor x\rfloor.$$

Comment: What to do if it is asked to choose between 2 and 3?

Comment: In that case the answer would be $3$: the reason being that the limit is taken before applying the function.

Answer (score 2):

It is not true that

$$\lfloor0.9999\cdots\rfloor=0.$$

You might argument that

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}{\lfloor0.\underbrace{999\cdots9}_n\rfloor}=\lim_{n\to\infty}0=0.$$

But this is not admissible as the $\text{floor}$ function is discontinuous (precisely at integer values).

The notation $$0.999\cdots$$ also $$0.\bar9$$ does not specify a finite number of nines, it is truly a second writing for $$1$$ and

$$\lfloor0.9999\cdots\rfloor=\lfloor1\rfloor\ne\lim_{n\to\infty}{\lfloor0.\underbrace{999\cdots9}_n\rfloor}.$$

Answer (score 0):

Set $x=2.999\dots$. Then $10x=29.999\dots$. Now substract to obtain $10x-x=9x=29.999\dots-2.999\dots=27$. Thus $9x=27\Leftrightarrow x=3$. qed